# Website login and download from multiple pages in one authenticated session

Tags: c#, authentication, session, download

Trying to login to a vendor website and gather information about many parts. I have read a multitude of posts, articles, and blogs -- most explain how I ought to be able to use CookieAwareWebClient to retain my authentication through a cookie automatically in all the subsequent requests.

```
public static void WebDownloads() {
   byte[] response;
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

   using (var wc = new CookieAwareWebClient()) {
      var values = new NameValueCollection { { "username", "myname@mydomain.net" }, { "password", "Th3p@55w0rD" }, };
      response = wc.UploadValues("https://sso.targetdomain.com:8443", values);

      // one of the comments suggests cookie is not being 'set'
      // wc.CookieContainer.Add(); //<-- add what from where?

      // this string array is just a small sample of part numbers for testing
      string[] strarr = { "400298", "404165", "375601" };
      foreach (string partno in strarr) {
         string html = wc.DownloadString($"https://secure.targetdomain.com/products/product/{partno}");
         string fName = $@"C:\temp\{partno}.htm";
         File.WriteAllText(fName, html); 
         // each one of these files is a trimmed down version of the login screen
      }
   }
}
```

I keep getting a login page. What I need are the pages with the part number information. Is the sso. or the :8443 significant to the necessary solution?

I installed Wireshark, did a capture, and isolated the ip address but I don't really know what to look for. No, I don't know if this is available as a service. One comment from 2017 stated that: You don't have to override GetWebRequest anymore. I am thoroughly confused, please help.